# Do limiting resistors always need to be used when driving logic level ICs from microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, current-limiting, mosfet-driver, circuit-protection

I have a circuit that uses a micro-controller and some driver ICs. The driver ICs state they are logic compatible and the data sheet says that the inputs maximum turn-on volate is 2.7v.

Some driver ICs are powered by the same 3.3v that the micro-controller is running at, and other driver ICs are 12v, but they still say they turn on at 2.7v. So I'm thinking I'm good there.

But the data sheet also says that if I am using diodes to protect the circuit against accidental reverse polarity connection, then I should put some limiting resistors in the line from the micro-controller to the logic level inputs of the driver ICs.

I understand why this is done, or I think I do, in that it limits the current and prevents lockup of the ICs due to the implicit SCR formed by the protection diodes. The data sheets go on to recommend at least 10k resistors.

I do not use the diodes in the group to protect against accidental polarity reversal, but I do have an active polarity protection circuit using two back-to-back FETs in the power side of the circuit using an LM-5050-1 IC.

Do I still need to put the 10k resistors in the circuit or can I do without them? Or is it just a good idea to always provide them no matter what?

Comment: Unless you are doing logic-level shifts between the microcontroller and the drivers, and this doesn't seem to be the case, neither resistors or diodes are needed.  Diodes are sometimes but not always used for the input power to protect against accidental reversal, but I have never heard of them used in logic lines for this purpose.  In any case, they wouldn't be used unless you were connecting to an off-board circuit.

Comment: It's possible that you have misunderstood that secret datasheet ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your microcontroller's output is compatible with the driver's input if the controllers minimum output voltage (V<sub>OL</sub>) is at least as high as the driver's minimum input voltage (V<sub>IL</sub>). Please note that V<sub>OL</sub> depends on the current that flows, so you have to check that the current that the driver needs is inside the controller's allowed range. (CMOS inputs have a very high impedance; this matters only if your driver uses actual BJTs.)

Limiting resistors are needed to protect the diodes against too much current. If you do not have such diodes (and if the driver does not have them), then you do not need resistors.

Comment: I read somewhere that all digital I/O should go through 100 Ohm resistors to suppress ringing /overshoot if it's fast(?)

Comment: @PaulUszak Transmission line effects are not what this question is about. And in most cases, 100 Ω is likely to result in an overdampened signal.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is always needed. It is just that it is advisable to always use them, to protect against the unexpected.